# How to slice several strings in a list?

Tags: python, string, list, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a list like

```
my_list = ['#005', '#003', '#002']
```

and I'd like a list with `['005','003','002']`. What I'm looking for is something like `map([:1], mylist)`. Does it exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use list comprehension, to strip the first character like this

```
>>> my_list = ['#005', '#003', '#002']
>>> [item[1:] for item in my_list]
['005', '003', '002']
```

if you want to use the `map` function, you need to pass a function to it, which does the same stripping, like this

```
>>> map(lambda item: item[1:], my_list)
['005', '003', '002']
```

Here we pass a [lambda expression](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions) to the map, which gets each and every item and returns the stripped string.

Alternatively, you can use the [`str.lstrip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.lstrip) function idiomatically, like this

```
>>> [item.lstrip('#') for item in my_list]
['005', '003', '002']
```

The same `lstrip` function can be used with `map` like this

```
>>> map(lambda item: item.lstrip('#'), my_list)
['005', '003', '002']
```

**Note:** If you are using Python 3.x, then the [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) returns an iterable `map` object. You need to iterate it and convert that to a list, like this

```
>>> my_list = ['#005', '#003', '#002']
>>> map(lambda item: item[1:], my_list)
<map object at 0x7fa6b301ef98>
>>> list(map(lambda item: item[1:], my_list))
['005', '003', '002']
```

As, [scott_fakename mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28778321/how-to-slice-several-strings-in-a-list/28778338?noredirect=1#comment45834566_28778338), you can give the functional touch to this problem, like this

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> list(map(itemgetter(slice(1, None)), my_list))
['005', '003', '002']
```

This uses [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) and [`slice`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#slice) function (which does the same job as the `[1:]` form).

Comment: @pedroabreu In Python, [the BDFL prefers List Comprehension over `map`](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196)

Comment: Also, if you want to use map, you can use `import operator; map(operator.itemgetter(slice(start, stop, step))`.

Not saying you should use this, just saying it's an option that exists. `slice(start, stop, step)` is what `item[start:stop:step]` receives, and `operator.itemgetter` is a function that calls slice on an object.

It's worth looking into because it's a useful thing to know about.

Comment: @thefourtheye Yeah, as a haskell lover I'm way to used with map to stop using it all of a sudden now in python haha. In fact list comprehation seems a lot more natural than map in python. But thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [120]: my_list = ['#005', '#003', '#002']

In [121]: new_list = [ele[1:] for ele in my_list]

In [122]: new_list
Out[122]: ['005', '003', '002']
```